# Is there online software that can let me plot a vector function in a different basis?

Tags: vector-spaces, math-software

If I have a vector valued function with components $x_1= \sin(t)$ and $x_2= \cos(t)$, is there a site where I can just quickly see what it looks like with a basis like $<0, 1,2>, <-1,-1/2>$?

Comment: Hint: What does $x_1^2+x_2^2$ equal?

Comment: That's awfully condescending. I am looking for online access in the general case and provided a simple example to explain the goal.

Comment: You’ve got a typo somewhere in the first vector of your basis.

Comment: GeoGebra and, I assume, Desmos, too, will let you apply a transformation matrix to function plots and other objects.

Comment: My comment was not meant to be condescending. Your question makes it look like you couldn't see what your example looked like and wanted a software tool to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parametric feature of Runiter's Graphing Calculator 3D.
Set the graph type to Parametric, then type in your function (except you have to use "u" variable instead of "t"):

```
x=sin(u)
y=cos(u)
z=u
```

This will plot a 3D curve with a spring-like shape.